# How to filter in an ARM template output by a property value?

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager

So I have my template deploying to azure and I would like to get a specific item from the returning array to pass into the following step in my pipeline. At the moment I am using the index of the item  to get the value and this works okay but this is susceptible to change in the future. How do I get by name in an ARM template?

Returning JSON from the function:

```
{
  "value": [
    { 
      "name": "primary", 
      "value": "firstvalue"
    },
    { 
      "name": "secondary", 
      "value": "secondValue"
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently working code that uses the index:

```
  "outputs": {
    "myOutput": {
      "value": "[myFunction.value[1].value]",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
```

I would like to get the item from the array by name, in C# it would be something like.

```
array.First(x => x.name == "secondary");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not expect to do any filtering (returning a subset of the array) but you are confident that there will be only one value with particular `"name"`, use object instead and reference it by simple `myOutput.primary`

so your output should be something like this:

```
"outputs": {
  "test": {
    "type": "object",
    "value": {
      "primary": "firstValue",
      "secondary": "secondValue"
    }
  }
}
```

and then use it (if we're talking about outputs from deployment) `reference(resourceId(..)).outputs.test.value.primary`